# visual studio: is it possible to color custom tags in code?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible somehow to color specified code in specified color in any version of visual studio? For example, make background of

```
if( VERIFY( ... ) )
```

green and background of

```
if( ! VERIFY( ... ) )
```

red? Maybe some addon exists or some version of visual studio has such functionality?

Comment: You can write your own addin anytime you like, can't you. I thought it would be complicated and it is, since VS extensibility frameworks is a big huge mess, but with lots of patience it can be done. I've done it, so can anybody else.

Comment: Have you written a normal addin (code that inherits IDTExtensibility2) or an "Visual Studio Extensibility" package? Writing addin is painful, but i can do it. Writing extensibility package is pure hell :(

Comment: Could you please explain the question a bit more, are you taking about the spell corrections or the case rules of naming conventions.

Comment: I just want to color specific text in specific color for code readability, nothing more as stated in my example, so text "if( VERIFY" is colored, for example, green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s "ToDo Items" to accomplish this.

- Resharper -> Options
- Create a pattern.
  Here you can specify the color, pattern, icon etc. This should already give you colorized code, the rest is optional, but makes it easier to find the patterns.
  (look at existing patterns for the syntax, or check the docs)
- You can use filters to find the patterns, and combinations of patterns
  You could create a filter that contains both your patterns for instance.
- use Resharper -> Tools -> ToDo-Items to search for the patterns

Comment: Resharper is good, but it is for C# only :(. And my main focus is C/C++/text :(

Comment: That's a shame, didn't realize that :(

Answer (score 4):

**NO PLUGIN NEEDED**

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [this tutorial](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/vctips), you can set **user-defined keywords** for syntax highlighting in a 
`usertype.dat` file, which you should save in the same directory as Visual Studio's `msdev.exe`, or `devenv.exe` for VS.NET.

Now restart Visual Studio.
Then in VS you can set the font properties for those keywords.

Edit: BTW, see the download [here](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/V-S/tips/syntaxhighlighting/article.php/c471/) for a predefined usertype.dat with *a lot* of keywords ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of an existing addin that does anything like that but I do know that Developer Express, the company that makes CodeRush, makes the addin engine freely available as a product called [DxCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/). This makes is much easier to create an addin that decorates the Visual Studio text editor. In Visual Studio 2010, a lot of the extremely difficult code that DxCore abstracts is no longer necessary as there is an official extensibility model for decorating the editor.

Here's a link to [some DxCore plugin samples](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/) on Google Code.

Comment: As i can see, where is no existing DxCore plugin available that can color specified text?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you may be interested in [FxCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis), it's more elaborate, but it should allow you the ability to detect the case you're talking about (via a custom rule, if it doesn't exist). It may be more work to set up, but it's worth it (especially if work in a team, and/or, have an existing CI system).

Comment: Fxcop does not highlight syntax? And it's only for specific languages like visual basic etc, and i need for c/c++ :(

Comment: Ah, bugger about the languages. I was suggesting to use it to enforce style rules about the way if statements were written (I was taking much liberty with the underlying question :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the VS Extensibility form Moderator, Ed Dore, it is not possible:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/93fc6d61-cfdb-432d-8541-d7dce498cef5/

> Unfortunately, no. The code implementing the document tabbing was developed with native Win32 code, and currently doesn't have any VS SDK or automation hooks into it.

It is too bad as this would be beyond useful.  (Keep track of different types of files and such.)

Comment: Visual Assist doing it somehow ^_^

Comment: And, furthermore, he speaks about tabs atop of text editor. And i simply need to color some text in text editor :)

Comment: If you had an answer why didn't you post it for all to benefit and save time of others trying to answer it...

Comment: Though I admit that I misread your question, I thought you wanted colored tabs not tags.